# How to avoid default boolean value in mutableStateOf

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to implement a feature where a user can add to favourite when state is true and delete from favourite when the state is false( The state change happens from a single button).   The issue is I set the mutableStateOf default value as false, so when i initially run the app the favourite gets deleted  automatically as I have set the favourite to Delete when the state is false... What I'm trying to achieve is to make the favourite add or delete only when the button is clicked

Edit:

```
WallpapersDetailScreen:
     @Composable
    fun WallpapersDetailScreen(
       wallpapersSharedViewModel: WallpapersSharedViewModel,
       mainViewModel: MainViewModel
    ) {
    
       var toState by remember { mutableStateOf(MultiFabState.COLLAPSED) }
       val showDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
       var updateFavoriteStatus = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    
    
       val imageUrl = wallpapersSharedViewModel.imageItem?.url
       val imageId = wallpapersSharedViewModel.imageItem?.id
    
       val userId = mainViewModel.dataStoreData.value
    
    
       val context = LocalContext.current
       val tag = "WallpapersDetailScreen"
    
    
       val items = listOf(
           MultiFabItem(
               identifier = FabIdentifier.FAVOURITE.name,
               icon = ImageBitmap.imageResource(id = R.drawable.heart),
               label = "favourite"
           ),
    
           MultiFabItem(
               identifier = FabIdentifier.SET_AS_WALLPAPER.name,
               icon = ImageBitmap.imageResource(id = R.drawable.wallpaper),
               label = "Set As Wallpaper"
           ),
    
           MultiFabItem(
               identifier = FabIdentifier.DOWNLOAD.name,
               icon = ImageBitmap.imageResource(id = R.drawable.download),
               label = "Download"
           ),
    
           MultiFabItem(
               identifier = FabIdentifier.SHARE.name,
               icon = ImageBitmap.imageResource(id = R.drawable.share),
               label = "Share"
           )
       )
       val postFavourite = imageId?.let { PostFavourite(it, userId) }
    
    
       Scaffold(
           floatingActionButton = {
               MultiFloatingActionButton(
                   fabIcon = Icons.Outlined.Add,
                   toState = toState,
                   items = items,
                   stateChanged = { state -> toState = state },
                   onFabItemClicked = { item ->
                       when (item.identifier) {
                           FabIdentifier.FAVOURITE.name ->updateFavoriteStatus.value = !updateFavoriteStatus.value
    //
                               FabIdentifier.SET_AS_WALLPAPER.name
                           -> showDialog.value = true
    //
                           FabIdentifier.DOWNLOAD.name -> imageUrl?.let {
                               downloadImage(
                                   tag, context,
                                   it
                               )
                           }
    //
    //                        FabIdentifier.SHARE.name -> TODO
    
                       }
                   }
               )
           },
    
           floatingActionButtonPosition = FabPosition.End
       ) {
           if (imageUrl != null) {
               ScreenContent(imageUrl)
           }
    
           if (showDialog.value) {
               if (imageUrl != null) {
                   WallpaperCustomDialog(
                       setShowDialog = { showDialog.value = it },
                       imageUrl = imageUrl,
                       context = context,
                       tag = tag
                   )
               }
           }
    
           if (updateFavoriteStatus.value == true) {
               postFavourite?.let {
                   wallpapersSharedViewModel.postFavourite(
                       it
                   )
               }
    
               val toast = Toast.makeText(context, "added to fav", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
               toast.show()
           }
           else{
               val toast = Toast.makeText(context, "deleted fav", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
               toast.show()
           }
    
       }
    
    
    }
    
    @Composable
    fun ScreenContent(imageUrl: String) {
       Column(
           modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
       ) {
           AsyncImage(
               modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
               model = imageUrl,
               contentDescription = null,
               contentScale = ContentScale.FillHeight
           )
       }
    }
```

Comment: I never touch Compose before so I can be mistaken. You have a FAB that may do delete or make it favourite, right ? How do the screen know which it should be, delete or favourite when you are not passing any parameter or get the instructiom from the sharedViewModel ?

Answer (score 4):

What you are doing is relying on recomposition to modify state, which you should not be doing. Composition depends on state, and [modifying state drives recomposition](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-and-composition), if recomposition modifies state, you can end up with a potentially infinite loop of compositions. Ideally composables are free from side-effects, and if you need one off events, then you will need to make use of the likes of `LaunchedEffect` or other compose lifecycle aware methods (see the [docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects) for others).

The proper way to accomplish what you are doing is in the `viewModel` directly

```kotlin
@Composable
fun WallpapersDetailScreen(
    wallpapersSharedViewModel: WallpapersSharedViewModel,
    mainViewModel: MainViewModel
) {

    Scaffold(){
        MultiFloatingActionButton(onFabItemClicked = { item ->
            wallpaperSharedViewModel.toggleFavorite(item)
        })
    }
}
```

```kotlin
class WallpapersSharedViewModel: ViewModel {
    fun toggleFavorite(item: Item) {
        // Do the logic here to either add or remove from favorites
    }
}
```

Doing it this way removes the logic from and cleans up the view code (composable) considerably. If you want to indicate whether or not a given item is a favorite, get that information from the viewModel as well (that is the whole point of a viewModel, holding and managing the information required to draw the UI and providing methods for the UI to change the model)

Comment: That's what i'm thinking, im really confused what is the fab's role. Btw, the provided code snippet from OP may be mixed from different sources (wrong close bracket), which make me more confused than ever.

Comment: ah yep, sorry about that I cut the code so that it won't be too long..  should I paste the full code instead ?...  The fab role is to add/delete from favorite

Comment: Posting the full code would be better than what you've included. However, if the code is indeed long, crafting usable snippets that give the gist of the problem make it easier to take in, and what you've included references values that aren't defined and has mismatched bracing which kind of threw me off creating my answer using your code, but I think I've answered the question effectively given what I had available so what you had is kinda "good enough", if it is not enough to get you to a working solution, then more details would be able to provide a better more relevant answer.

Comment: @Sky it's been a while, but did my proposed solution solve your problem? If so, could you mark the answer as accepted?

Comment: Hi @undermark5, sorry I didn't see ur previous comment... yep ur solution  was very helpful but I couldn't  find a way to implement  the logic for the toggle favorite  in a single button.. I ended up using two buttons for that... And I perform the Add/delete operations from Api calls.. so I wasn't sure how I could handle the state